# Unable to create Sales Order via API with items from Inactive Vendor

Tags: acumatica

When attempting to create a Sales Order via an API call, if the Vendor marked as Default for any item on the order has status Inactive an error is returned with the message: "PX.Data.PXException: The vendor status is 'Inactive'"

However, when creating the Sales Order through the standard Screen there is no issue with ordering items with Inactive Default Vendors.

We want to keep the Vendors marked as Inactive but need to create the Sales Orders for the items like the Screen allows. How can this be done?

Comment: The message is received using the screen, but only as a warning found in the trace window. I would think warnings would not be presented in the API calls (only errors). The message is coming from the restrictor on SOLine.VendorID. To resolve as is, via extension on the site override the field verifying or in the API call null out the vendor ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the error is coming from SOLine.VendorID from Brendan comment.

Here are the steps to debug that problem and fix it using FieldVerifying event.

**Add SOLine.VendorID field on SalesOrder screen:**
[image]

**Reproduce the error in SalesOrder using the field you added:**
[image]

**Check trace error, it indicates the error is coming from a PXRestrictor attribute:**
[image]

**Check VendorID field, it has a PXRestrictor and the VendorIsInStatus error message you receive:**
[image]

**PXRestrictor attribute validation can be cancelled using the FieldVerifying event, add that handler to SalesOrder for SOLine.VendorID:**

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected void SOLine_VendorID_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

**Test SalesOrder again, if it works you can remove the VendorID/VendorName you added to the grid to debug:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From Brendan's comment I went with modifying the PXRestrictor attribute of the SOLine.VendorID to allow Inactive status as well:

```
public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine> {
  [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
  [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Vendor.status, IsNull,
            Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.active>,
            Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.inactive>,
            Or<Vendor.status, Equal<BAccount.status.oneTime>>>>>), PX.Objects.AP.Messages.VendorIsInStatus, typeof(Vendor.status))]
  public virtual Int32? VendorID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: an alternative might be to extend field verifying for SOLine.VendorID and look at IsImport, IsMobile, and/or IsContractBasedAPI and adjust the logic as needed. For example you can have it validate unless using contract web services (myGraph.IsContractBasedAPI == true).